# How can I point Tezbox to my own node?

Tags: node, rpc, tezbox

So I have a node and a baker running. I would like to know how can I get Tezbox to connect to it from LAN or the Internet. Apparently it needs SSL connection but I guess it can work with Snake Oil Certs and some trickery. My Node is also reachable via DDNS and it doesn't have a static IP. This means I cannot just get a domain and buy an SSL cert.

Thanks for your help!